# About javascript/jquery working with DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

My question is how to integrate count1 in the "#clickCount" div with SPAN?

Instead of looking like:

- You've clicked on a card: 1,2..(in String) times

I want it to look like:

- You've clicked on a card: (1,2....)

In other words I want "count1" to be custom span in the div.

It's important to note that this refreshes every second.

```
function pretty_time_string(num) {
    return ( num < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + num;
}

var start = new Date;

setInterval(function () {
    var total_seconds = (new Date - start) / 1000;

    var hours = Math.floor(total_seconds / 3600);
    total_seconds = total_seconds % 3600;

    var minutes = Math.floor(total_seconds / 60);
    total_seconds = total_seconds % 60;

    var seconds = Math.floor(total_seconds);

    hours = pretty_time_string(hours);
    minutes = pretty_time_string(minutes);
    seconds = pretty_time_string(seconds);

    currentTimeString = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    $("#clickCount").text("You've clicked on a card: " + count1 + " times." + " Correct guesses of pairs: " + count2 + "." + " Play Time: " + currentTimeString);


}, 1000);
```

I've spent on more than 5 hours on this problem, still no progress.

```
$("#clickCount").text("You've clicked on a card: " + count1 + " times."
  + " Correct guesses of pairs: " + count2 + "." + " Play Time: " 
  + currentTimeString);
```

Comment: You need something like this? `$("#clickCount").html("You've clicked on a card: <span>" + count1 + "</span> times." + " Correct guesses of pairs: " + count2 + "." + " Play Time: " + currentTimeString);`

Comment: Thanks MAN ! ! ! ! Can't thank you enough...

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this? $("#clickCount").html("You've clicked on a card: " + count1 + " times." + " Correct guesses of pairs: " + count2 + "." + " Play Time: " + currentTimeString); –  TheGr8_Nik 1 hour ago

This guy helped me a lot! This solved my problem.

Can't thank you enough guys...